# Ternary operator in Python raises TypeError when using * operator on empty list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, ternary-operator

I want to print the contents of a list `a` if `len(a) > 0`, but otherwise I want to print `-1`. This seems to be pretty simple, but it's raising a `TypeError`, stating that `a` is an int, not a sequence, only when `a` is an empty list:

```
>>> a = [2]
>>> print(*a if len(a) > 0 else -1)
2 # as expected
>>> a = []
>>> print(*a)

>>> # It has no trouble evaluating *a when a is empty
... ### HERE IS THE ERROR:
...
>>> print(*a if len(a) > 0 else -1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
>>> ### But this works fine:
...
>>> if len(a) > 0:
...     print(*a)
... else:
...     print(-1)
...
-1
```

Why is this the case?

According to the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, `C` rather
>   than `x`. If `C` is true, `x` is evaluated and its value is returned;
>   otherwise, `y` is evaluated and its value is returned.

So `*a` shouldn't be getting evaluated at all, and yet it's causing a TypeError?

I'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but looking at [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448) it looks like this `*` syntax isn't part of the general expression syntax, but it's specific to function callsites (and other things like tuple and dictionary displays).  (It's a bit of a hack.)

The PEP explicitly calls out some similar syntax that they've forbidden because they didn't know what it should do.  It doesn't look like your code has been particularly considered though.

> Unbracketed comprehensions in function calls, such as f(x for x in it), are already valid. These could be extended to:
>
> f(*x for x in it) == f((*x for x in it))
>
> f(**x for x in it) == f({**x for x in it})
>
> However, it wasn't clear if this was the best behaviour
>   or if it should unpack into the arguments of the call to f. Since
>   this is likely to be confusing and is of only very marginal utility,
>   it is not included in this PEP. Instead, these will throw a
>   SyntaxError and comprehensions with explicit brackets should be used
>   instead.

I think your code is effectively parsing as `print(*(a if len(a) > 0 else -1))`, which is why you then get the error `TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not int`.  By comparison, this works:

```
>>> print(*a if len(a) > 0 else ['nothing'])
nothing
```

Comment: Very interesting. I see that if I instead write `print(*[-1] if not a else a)`, it prints exactly what I want. Now that I know how it parses, it shouldn't be a problem to deal with. Thanks!